# responseType: "json" header causing error: Property 'responseStatus' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: json, angular, http, header, response

I read before that It's more secure if you add the `responseType: "json"` header to your http requests so I would like to add it.

However when I use it, I get an error when treating the response as JSON (i.e with the dot notation).

For example when I try to get a property of the json response as follows: `res.responseStatus` , it throws an error:

```
"Property 'responseStatus' does not exist on type 'Object'."
```

If I take out the `responseType: "json"` header from the http request I don't get an error.

If I leave in the `responseType` header than I can get the properties of the object in the response by the following notation: `res["responseStatus"]` and this does not throw an error.
I'm just wondering if anyone knows why. Maybe I'm missing something.

Thanks

## Http post request code (from ionic app-angular 5)

```
  login(loginData): Observable<any>{   
    return this.http.post("http://localhost/api/auth", 
        {"emailAddress": loginData.emailAddress, "password": loginData.password},
        {"headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"}, responseType: "json"})
    .map(res => {
      if(res.responseStatus === "success"){
          //Throwing error: "Property 'responseStatus' does not exist on type 'Object'."
          //but If I say res["responseStatus"] instead this does not throw error.
          //Or If I take out the responseType header, I can use the dot notation.
      }
      return res;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response if you want to access the response, not just its content. You can also provide an interface that describes the *shape* of the response content, which makes your response handling code more type-safe.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for your information. I will do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient).

You'll need to add [`observe: 'response'`](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) to the [`httpOptions`](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers) to get the full response.

I've also specified the type of `res` as [`HttpResponse`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse). As Jon mentioned in his comments, that's not really required if you've used `observe: 'response'` in the `httpOptions`.

Also, it's `status` that you'll get and not `responseStatus`.

Give this a try:

```
login(loginData): Observable < any > {

  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    }),
    observe: 'response',
    responseType: "json"
  };

  return this.http.post("http://localhost/api/auth", loginData, httpOptions)
    .map((res: HttpResponse) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        ...
      }
      return res;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Well I built a php APi and one of the properties of my json is responseStatus that I set to success or error in the php API.

Comment: @Sarah, Okay. I wasn't aware of that. You should be able to still get it as `status` as the response returned is of type `HttpResponse`. Could you please check the response by printing it to the console to see what exactly do you get in the response. I think it should be `status` but let's check it just to confirm.

Comment: Hi @SiddAjmera I have tried this code. it works great. I printed out res and I can see the full HttpResponse. The property is indeed called "status". That's much better than what I was doing. Thanks so much :)

Comment: You shouldn't need to explicitly type `res` in the function signature; if `observe: 'response'` is in the options then the result of calling `.post` is already `Observable<HttpResponse<...>>`: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L1706

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks a lot. I'll keep that in mind. :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Any chance you edit the answer to show the changes you mean?